# Can't find ro.securestorage.support

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, android-10, wifi-password

I want to see my wifi passwords. I have a Samsung Galaxy M31 with Android 10, rooted with Magisk. I was told I could find my passwords on the wpa.supplicants.conf file, but it's practically blank. I only just now discovered that they are actually in the WifiConfigStore file, but are encrypted. Then I was told I could decrypt my passwords by editing the line on my build.prop file where it says "ro.securestorage.support" to false. But that line is nowhere to be found on my file. I would like to know how to make my wifi passwords non-encrypted, whether by editing these files or otherwise.

Comment: On recent Android versions you can simply display a QR code in Wifi settings to get the Wifi password. Just use a second device and a QR code reader app and point it on the QR code and you get the password. BTW: changing settings like `ro.securestorage.support` will not decrypt the password file, it will simply disable encryption support so all encrypted files are then unreadable which means you have to make a factory reset. FBE encrypted files should be automatically decrypted if you access them after entering the device PIN.

Comment: @Robert, thank you for the heads-up, glad it didn't work, then. But my android device does not show any password on the QR code screen - that was the first thing I tried. I am running Android 10. As for decryption, I can confirm that the password list in WifiConfigStore is encrypted, as my own password is a long string of numbers there instead of what it should be.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. If you can read the file and it doesn't contains binary gibberish then the file is not encrypted, only the WiFi passphrase in the file may be encrypted/protected. But it could be simply that the passphrase is never saved and instead the raw key is saved (which is what is actually used by the WiFi stack). The key is generated from the passphrase.

Comment: @Robert, it's fine, I should have mentioned it in the main post. But if it's the case that the passphrase isn't saved, then does that mean there's no way to view saved wifi passwords on my device at all?

Comment: If it is really the WiFi key then there is no good way back. If you just want to establish a connection to that WiFi you can simply use the key. The WiFi stack should recognize that you have entered a key and not a passphrase and simply skip the conversation to the key and directly use the key.

Comment: I see. I think you're right; the WifiConfigStore section listing them says "PreSharedKeys". Strangely enough, the Wi-Fi Password Viewer app shows entirely different strings of numbers, so I guess it's either showing the actual, encrypted passwords or it's lying to me. But anyway, I'm not sure how to do what you suggested of using the key as a password. Any advice on how to do that? Or a way to find and read the actual passwords?

Comment: I believe Robert's statement about the QR code is to scan the QR code because [the standard format (almost) always contains the passphrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Joining_a_Wi%E2%80%91Fi_network). Just make sure that it's not a QR code from Samsung's Quick Share because it's Samsung's proprietary link.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?  Why do you need to see the "stored passwords"?

Comment: Well, it's like this: my phone has a lot of passwords stored from various places, and I wanted to be able to simply check those passwords and so connect to them with my computer as well. I have tried finding the passwords with the QR code screen (doesn't show them, which is apparently a Samsung issue), accessing the WifiConfigStore (doesn't have them, it seems) and using an app (which appears to show them in encrypted form). I just wanted to be able to see my phone's stored wifi passwords with the same ease as I can on a computer. And thus be able to access them on other devices.

Comment: Sorry, it's just that it's been a while. @Robert? @RohitGupta? Can you help?